# Google Translate API How to translate big text ((414) Request-URI Too Large) with .NET library

Tags: c#, .net, google-translate

I am using .NET library http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Translate_API for translating texts, but I can't translate big texts, just small one.

I am getting error (414) Request-URI Too Large. There should be some way how to do this.

I have this code

```
        var service = new TranslateService();
        service.Key = this.ApiKey;

        var request = service.Translations.List(textToTranslate, this.LngDestination);
        request.Source = this.LngSource;

        TranslationsListResponse response = request.Fetch();

        foreach (TranslationsResource translation in response.Translations)
        {
            return translation.TranslatedText;
        }
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: If the request URI is too large, it's an indication that a GET request is performed. A POST request would transport the text to translate in the message payload, not in the request URI. Check if you can configure the library you're using in some way that it uses POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#Translate) for this project says,

> Note: You can also use POST to invoke the API if you want to send more data in a single request. The q parameter in the POST body must be less than 5K characters. To use POST, you must use the X-HTTP-Method-Override header to tell the Translate API to treat the request as a GET (use X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET).

If you want help switching to `POST`, include the relevant code from your `TranslateService()` object.

Comment: I know this, but I don't know how to do that. I am using this class provided by Google http://wsdl.mirodre.sk/Google.Apis.Translate.v2.cs.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to modify it.